# How to implement VERTICAL pagecontrol in iPad/ iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipagecontrol

I am aware of the procedure to implement horizontal page control. But i am very curios to know if we can implement page control **VERTICALLY**. For example, if the user swipes up, he goes to 2nd page and then the 2nd dot of the pagecontrol gets highlighted. (Remember  - The page control is vertical in this case)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wouldn't `pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);` suffice?

Comment: You are right. This should work too, much better answer than mine.

Comment: I am facing this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65789901/vertically-rotated-uipagecontrol-taking-too-much-space the UIPageControl takes too much space

Answer (score 1):

If you are refering to the UIPageControl item, then you will have to create it yourself as none exists (could exist as a small library on github though)

If you are looking for the page scrolling effect (you can swiperup & down to navigate through full screen pages), then you will have to look at a standard UIScrollView with the `pagingEnabled` property set to YES.

Answer (score 0):

one method is to 
rotate a scrollview 90° , rotate contents -90°, should created a convenience method for converting frame from one angle to another