# Vertically rotated UIPageControl taking too much space

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uipagecontrol

I used `CGAffineTransform` to rotate a horizontal UIPageControl vertical. But when I added it besides my collection view it's taking too much width. And when I add a width anchor on it, the UIPageControl disappears.

```
noticesPagingIndicator = UIPageControl()
let angle = CGFloat.pi/2
noticesPagingIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
```

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
//            noticesPagingIndicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            noticesPagingIndicator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            noticesPagingIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: noticesCollectionView.centerYAnchor),
            noticesCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: noticesPagingIndicator.trailingAnchor),
            noticesCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: noticeStackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            noticesCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            noticesCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor)
 ])
```

[image: page control taking too much width]

When I look at the UIView hierarchy, I see a lot of padding along the UIPageControl

[image: UI view hierarchy with too much width for page controller]

With the width anchor enabled:

[image]
[image: with width anchor]

Comment: Try to give minus constant to this constraint: noticesCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: noticesPagingIndicator.trailingAnchor)

Comment: I could do that but isn't it a hack! I feel the affine transform is causing this issue.

Comment: Yes, it because when you transform, it takes its bounds.

Comment: Can't we fix it so the bounds also get rotated?

Comment: Change height constant instead of width.

Comment: That did not help only 1 dot was visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get to know the `Debug View Hierarchy` tool. It can help you figure out most layout issues.

When you transform a view, that doesn't change its bounds and thus doesn't change its constraint relationships to other UI elements.

With this code (8 pages, so 8 dots):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let pgc = UIPageControl()
    let greenLabel = UILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        pgc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        greenLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(pgc)
        view.addSubview(greenLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // page control Leading to safe area Leading + 20, centerY
            pgc.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pgc.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain greenLabel Leading to page control trailing + 8 and centerY, safe area trailing -8
            greenLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pgc.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            greenLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pgc.centerYAnchor),
            greenLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
        ])

        // rotate the page control
        let angle = CGFloat.pi/2
        pgc.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
        
        pgc.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        greenLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        
        pgc.numberOfPages = 8
        
        greenLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        greenLabel.text = "UIPageControl indicates the number of open pages in an application by displaying a dot for each open page. The dot that corresponds to the currently viewed page is highlighted. UIPageControl supports navigation by sending the delegate an event when a user taps to the right or to the left of the currently highlighted dot."
        
    }
    
}
```

You get this output:

[image]

As you've seen, the Green Label Leading constraint to the page control Trailing Anchor shows the page control **width** matches what it would be without the rotation.

If you inspect the views with `Debug View Hierarchy`, you'll see the page control looks like this:

[image]

The **frame** is `w: 27.5 h: 217` but the **bounds** is `w: 217 h: 27.5`.

To fix this, you need to embed the page control in a "holder" view, constrain the holder view's Height to the page control's Width and Width to Height. Then constrain your other elements to that "holder" view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let pgcHolder = UIView()
    let pgc = UIPageControl()
    let greenLabel = UILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        pgcHolder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pgc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        greenLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
        pgcHolder.addSubview(pgc)
        view.addSubview(pgcHolder)
        view.addSubview(greenLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // center page control in its "holder" view
            pgc.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pgcHolder.centerXAnchor),
            pgc.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pgcHolder.centerYAnchor),
            
            // constrain holder view leading to view + 20, centerY
            pgcHolder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pgcHolder.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain holder view WIDTH to page control HEIGHT
            pgcHolder.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pgc.heightAnchor),
            // constrain holder view HEIGHT to page control WIDTH
            pgcHolder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pgc.widthAnchor),
            
            // constrain greenLabel Leading to holder view trailing + 8 and centerY, safe area trailing -8
            greenLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pgcHolder.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            greenLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pgcHolder.centerYAnchor),
            greenLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
        ])
        
        let angle = CGFloat.pi/2
        pgc.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)

        pgcHolder.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        pgc.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        greenLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        
        pgc.numberOfPages = 8
        
        greenLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        greenLabel.text = "UIPageControl indicates the number of open pages in an application by displaying a dot for each open page. The dot that corresponds to the currently viewed page is highlighted. UIPageControl supports navigation by sending the delegate an event when a user taps to the right or to the left of the currently highlighted dot."

    }
    
}
```

Now we have our desired output:

[image]

Comment: You know so much about iOS Development! 

Comment: Just one question, I have seen that if I have like 20 posts then only 4-5 dots are shown with the one small dot before and or after the  4-5 dots indicating that more posts are left. In that case, do I really need to set the height constraint? What happens if we set the top and the bottom anchor? Then will the page control act according to the way I have seen it behave? Or that only happens in iOS 14?

Comment: @ParthTamane - experiment with it. Start with a standard, non-rotated `UIPageControl` and note the differences between iOS 14 and earlier. Prior to 14, if you have more "dots" than will fit in the available width, what do you do? Once you've decided how you want to handle that, then see how it's affected when you rotate it. Completely different question from this one though.

Comment: @ParthTamane - remember to mark answers as Accepted, for the benefit of other users who may come across it.

Comment: Yup sorry forgot

Answer (score 0):

@DonMag Answer with storyboard

Step 1 :

In View Controller, Drag UIVIew  --> Name it (holderView)

Step 2 :

Drag Page Control in the holderView

Step 4:

Select the holder View  - add Center Y Constraint , Trailing Constraint with Super View

Step 5:

Select the page Control View - add Center X , Center Y constraint

Step 6 :

From the View List on left panel , select both parent view and page control view , add Equal With and Equal Height constraint

Step 7:

Now select the Equal Width  constraint and from left panel (properties of constraint)  update superView Width to SuperView Height ,

Same for Height Constraint

Your Constraint should look like this

[image]